# Multidimensional input to Keras LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47726870/how-can-i-reshape-my-data-for-keras-lstm-input), but my question is slightly different.

In an LSTM in Keras, the input is expected to be in the format (samples, time steps, features). For example, if my training set has 500 examples, and each example has sequence length 60, and at each time point there are two features (like temperature and humidity), then my input (if I were to feed in the entire training set at once) would have shape (500, 60, 2).

However, what if the 'features' is another array, of shape (75, 4)? How can this be fed in as input per time step? Keras won't accept an LSTM input shape of (500, 60, 75, 4).

Comment: You could try a cnn, also can you explain why your features have features? Or is this just additional time steps, (I.e. first sequences is days second sequence is hours)

Comment: Thank you, but I need to use an LSTM. I have 75 nodes in a network. If I consider the adjacency matrix, that's of dimension (75, 75). Each node has a feature, that is one of four possible things (it's a categorical feature). Hence (75, 75, 4). I can express this, though, as (75, 4), because each node has 1 of 4 features.

Comment: What if you just `flatten` your (75, 4)-array?

Comment: I did that in a separate model in another context, but I'm worried that by flattening I'll lose the idea of 'node 1 has property 2', etc. What do you think?